# Inertia form redireciona após submeter

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Olá, tenho os seguintes códigos:

**Frontend:**

```
function SalvarPagina(){

    closeModal.value.click()

   const form = useForm({
        titulo: page.nome,
        id_categoria: page.id_categoria,
        ativar: page.ativar,
   });

   form.put(route('paginas.editar', {id:page.id}), {

        onError: (errors) => {

            toastComponente.value.toast(errors);
        },

        onSuccess: (res) => {

            toastComponente.value.toast(res.props.flash.success, 'Icon');
        },

        onFinish: function(){

        },
    });
}
```

**Backend/Laravel:**

```
public function updatePage($id, $request){

        $request->validate([
            'titulo' => ['required', 'max:50'],
            'id_categoria' => ['required'],
            'ativar' => ['required'],
        ]);

        $page = $this->paginas->find($id);
        $page->update($request->all());

        Debugbar::info($request->all());

        return Redirect::back()->with([
            'success' => 'Página atualizada com sucesso!',
        ]);
    }
```

Esse código ele pega os dados e envia para a rota **/paginas/editar/{id}** do laravel. Ele está enviando e processando corretamente.

**Meu problema e o que preciso:**

Eu estou acessando a rota **/paginas** e lá tem todos os meus items e ele abre um modal para editar. Após eu clicar em salvar eu precisava que ele continuasse na mesma rota, no caso, **/paginas** mas aos clicar em salvar, ele está redirecionando para **/paginas/editar/{id}** . Eu precisava que ele apenas enviasse e se manter-se onde está.

Answer (score 1):

A função `Redirect::back()` irá renderizar a mesma página de onde veio a requisição, já que está solicitando de **/paginas/editar/{id}**, ele irá retornar para a mesma rota. Você poderá renderizar novamente a página que quer com a função nativa do laravel com rotas nomeadas: `return Redirect->route('pagina')` ou usar a função do Inertia `return Inertia::render('pagina')`. Lembrando-se que a função do Inertia não permite o uso de mensagens flash de sessões, teria que passar como props os dados de sucesso.